# Unable to compile and run HelloWorld in jdk1.7

Tags: java, java-7

I have installed `jdk1.7` at my `e:\`. i have already `jdk1.6` and `1.5` in my machine at `c:\`.

Environment vairable,

```
path=c:\jdk1.6\bin;e:\jdk1.7\bin;.;
classpath=c:\jdk1.6\lib;e:\jdk1.7\lib;.;
```

in cmd prompt,

```
E:\>java -version
java version “1.7.0″
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode, sharing)

E:\>set path=e:\javasdk1.7\bin;.;

E:\>javac
Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.javac.Main
```

Not able to compile a `Hello7.java` which is at `e:\`

enter code here

```
import java.io.*;
class Hello7 {
   public static void main(String... args) {
      String color="red";
      switch (color) {   
      case "red":   
         System.out.println("Color is Red");   
         break;   
      case "green":   
         System.out.println("Color is Green");   
         break;   
      default:   
         System.out.println("Color not found");   
      }  
   }
}
```

---

No Tom, Still am getting error while trying to compile. Pleae find the below status.

```
E:\>dir j*
 Volume in drive E is Keane
  Volume Serial Number is BA91-B3F6

 Directory of E:\

 10/04/2010  05:25 PM    <DIR>          j2ee1.4.tutorials
 08/18/2011  02:52 PM    <DIR>          Jar Files
 08/02/2011  11:33 AM    <DIR>          javasdk1.7
 07/01/2011  04:39 PM    <DIR>          jboss
 10/04/2010  05:25 PM    <DIR>          jsf
 10/04/2010  05:25 PM    <DIR>          junit
           0 File(s)              0 bytes
           6 Dir(s)  33,454,637,056 bytes free

  E:\>set path=e:\javasdk1.7\bin;.;

  E:\>set classpath=e:\javasdk1.7\lib;.;

  E:\>javac
  Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.javac.Main
```

Comment: Is your JDK in e:\jdk1.7 or e:\javasdk1.7? Your question is inconsistent. I'm also surprised that it shows up as Java 7 if you have JDK 6 first in your path...

Comment: Please check tools.jar, maybe it is damaged or missing

Comment: There is no need to look at the code since the problem is javac can not find tools.jar and hasn't even started on 'compiling' anything.  Have avoided windows for a decade at this point (and java/javac run fine on CentOS 6 simply from the unpacked tar.gz) but the issue is clearly environment settings. Get rid of the 1.6 in your classpath and try again.

Comment: I would suggest you use an IDE. It is designed to make development easier and switching between versions of Java is just a setting.

Comment: Peter, i tried with eclipse 3.6, in properties i am able to jre 1.7 and compiler 1.7, able to execute simple java code. while trying switch with string given compiler error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.

Answer (score 3):

JDK 6 in you path and class path appears before JDK 7. I believe this is the problem.

Try first to remove JDK 6 from classpath and path environment variables and then try again. If it will work you probably have to create bat file that sets the environment for java 7 and run it before working with java 7.

Alternatively just remove older versions of java. Why do you need them?

Comment: Remove older version from path, classpath in user and system environment variable, now totally 7 only. still same error

Answer (score 0):

In your classpath you have java 7 at e:\jdk1.7\lib;.;

Note the **jdk1.7**.

In you path you have java 7 at e:\jdk1.7\bin when you specify the environment vars, but then you set it to e:\javasdk1.7\bin in the line:

```
E:\>set path=e:\javasdk1.7\bin;.;
```

Note the **javasdk1.7**.

Since javac IS running, it seems the new PATH you set must be correct.  Your classpath should match it (removing, as others have noted, the reference to your java 7 install):

```
classpath=e:\javasdk1.7\lib;.;
```

Make that change and it should be able to find the missing class.